# How to deal with when useful answer or comment is deleted?

Tags: discussion, support

I've asked [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/847946/is-there-any-difference-between-domain-controller-and-active-directory) question and I remember that there is a one more answer posted. On that answer, comment by user **joeqwerty** was useful and i replied back but after few hours when i see answer was deleted and comment so. I do not remember the comment well so i could not discuss about it with other users.

I do remember that answer has up votes but might be user deleted but what to do when such things happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the author decided to remove the answer (which he did), you can't do anything. Please remember that Serverfault is not a forum.